# How can I downgrade the version Maven packages with

Tags: java, maven

Whenever I try and run a java package I have made it simply comes up with
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: frogge/the/dude/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`. I've attempted to change the maven.compiler.source and maven.compiler.target to version 8, yet it still comes up with the exact same error. I have barely used stack overflow so please tell me if I need to include anything else.

Comment: The JDK you are using to run is the wrong one. Just use `mvn --version` to show which JDK version your are using?

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer to my own question, I don't exactly know what the correlation is but, I had to run `mvn clean` and `mvn compile` before `mvn package` created the correct product

Comment: You probably needed to run `mvn clean`. The command `mvn compile` will not help.